# Center Google route on screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I would like to center a route that is returned from google directions api on the screen? I have tried to use CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds but it seems to limit the user from moving to a certain part of the map.

All i would like to do is show the route centered on the screen rather than my current location?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I managed to find a solution if anyone needs help with something similar. Although I am still trying to fix the calculating the zoom issue, where it doesn't zoom in to have the route fit in the screen as apposed to hard coding a zoom value

```
LatLng northEast = new LatLng(aBoundary.getNortheast().getLat(), aBoundary.getNortheast().getLng());
LatLng southWest = new LatLng(aBoundary.getSouthwest().getLat(), aBoundary.getSouthwest().getLng());
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngBounds.getCenter(), mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));
```

the `aBoundary` object is the `Bounds` object that sits inside the `Route` object from the response.